# adding class to element that the mouse is on

Tags: jquery, addclass, mousemove

I need a function that will add a class to a element that the mouse is on now. this has to change when the mouse moves, every were it goes that element should have the extra class.

I know how to get the x and y of a element using this

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
$().mousemove(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
});
```

but then how do i get the hole element in order to add the class?

Can any one here help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: You don't need to get the x and y, you just have to bind a `hover` event to all elements. The rest will be taken care of by jQuery for you. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thnak you. but I dont need the regular hover function that doesnt do what i need it to do, i need to know how to get the element according the the x and y position. the regular hover doesnt get me all the elements. I think it only gives me the div and not all the a and every thing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i was looking for:

```
$('*').hover(
    function (event) {
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        $(elem).addClass('khoverElem');
    },
    function (event) {
        $('.khoverElem').removeClass('khoverElem');

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

so any element the mouse hovers will get that class?

```
$('*').hover(function(){ $(this).addClass('theClass'); });
```

Comment: I dont need the regular hover function that doesnt do what i need it to do, i need to know how to get the element according the the x and y position. the regular hover doesnt get me all the elements.

Comment: I think it only gives me the div and not all the a and every thing else

Comment: @Ovi use offset() on the element that triggers the event. that might work.

Comment: @ Nicola Peluchetti can you please give me a example for using it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use-

1. [**mouseover**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

even you can use this code also- jquery has hust splitted `hover` in fallowing way-

```
$(".hoverme").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('special'); // mouse over
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('special'); // mouse out
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To know the element that triggered the event you can use the "target" property of the event and then get it's position using [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset)

```
$('*').mousemove(function (e) {
    var target = e.target //this is the element that triggered the evnt
    //do what you want with target: to get it's position:
     var position = $(target).offset()

});
```

EDIT use '*' to select all elements or attach it to document $(document)

P.S. be prepared to handle A LOT of events, i don't know how this could impact on performance.